# VB.NET I want to Login website without webbrowser control

Tags: vb.net

Normally i use webbrowser control to login website in VB.NET

e.g.   WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("username").SetAttribute("value", TextBox1.Text)
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("password").SetAttribute("value", TextBox2.Text)
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById(".login").InvokeMember("click")

If i not use webbrowser control to login , What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to build your own Http requests.

Have a look at [HttpWebRequest class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx)